# Pushing ABPersonViewController to ABPeoplePickerNavigationController on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, abpeoplepickerview, abpersonviewcontroller

Presenting the people picker

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
peoplePicker.allowsActions = YES;
peoplePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Implementing the ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate in iOS 7

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
  ABPersonViewController *personViewController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
  personViewController.displayedPerson = person;
  [peoplePicker pushViewController:personViewController animated:YES];
  return NO;
}
```

So far so good. The person view controller is presented as expected. iOS7 method returns a value - one could return **NO** in order to make sure the people picker remains open. In iOS8 the above delegate method was deprecated and new method must be implemented:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
  ABPersonViewController *personViewController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
  personViewController.displayedPerson = person;
  [peoplePicker pushViewController:personViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The person view controller is pushed to the people picker but after a fraction of a second the people picker is dismissed (together with the person view controller).

Is there a way to prevent the people picker from dismissing on iOS8? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What you were doing was always wrong. It was never correct to push ABPersonViewController onto ABPeoplePickerNavigationController like that. Rethink your interface.

Comment: Fundamentally, what are you trying to achieve? Why not let the people picker show you the person itself?

Comment: @Rob I want the ABPersonViewController to display the action buttons which are not displayed by default.

Comment: What if you want to display a custom detail view instead of the default view? It wouldn't be so bad if apple had used the public dismissModal method instead of a private API to dismiss the controller. Sloppy...

Comment: @matt Why it wrong was wrong on iOS 7? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController*)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{ 
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
      ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];

      [personController setDisplayedPerson:person];
      [personController setPersonViewDelegate:self];
      [personController setAllowsEditing:NO];
      personController.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty], nil];

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:personController animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `presentViewController` instead `pushViewController` ... in Xcode 6 it says that pushViewController is deprecated and I see you're trying to implement it in iOS8 so give it a try ...
Something like this line:

```
[peoplePicker presentViewController: personViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: I have the exact example but it is in swift ... So I think this should work.

Comment: It works but it is not what I was asking for. Thanks.

Comment: Probably I can't understand your question. You just want to show the action buttons ?

Comment: Show the action buttons but also push the person view controller into the people picker. You suggest to display the person view controller which replaces the people picker instead of being pushed to it.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS8, you will need to add code as below when you initialise the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController, otherwise the peoplePickerNavigationController will dismiss right away after you select a contact.

```
if(IOS8_OR_LATER){
    peoplePicker.predicateForSelectionOfPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:false]; }
```